# Python,Scrapy, Pipeline: function "process_item" not getting called

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline

I have a very simple code, shown below. Scraping is okay, I can see all `print` statements generating correct data. In `Pipeline`,initialization is working fine. However, `process_item` function is not getting called, as `print` statement at the start of the function is never executed.

Spider: comosham.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from activityadvisor.items import ComoShamLocation
from activityadvisor.items import ComoShamActivity
from activityadvisor.items import ComoShamRates
import re


class ComoSham(Spider):
    name = "comosham"
    allowed_domains = ["www.comoshambhala.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.comoshambhala.com/singapore/classes/schedules",
        "http://www.comoshambhala.com/singapore/about/location-contact",
        "http://www.comoshambhala.com/singapore/rates-and-offers/rates-classes",
        "http://www.comoshambhala.com/singapore/rates-and-offers/rates-classes/rates-private-classes"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):  
        category = (response.url)[39:44]
        print 'in parse'
        if category == 'class':
            pass
            """self.gen_req_class(response)"""
        elif category == 'about':
            print 'about to call parse_location'
            self.parse_location(response)
        elif category == 'rates':
            pass
            """self.parse_rates(response)"""
        else:
            print 'Cant find appropriate category! check check check!! Am raising Level 5 ALARM - You are a MORON :D'


    def parse_location(self, response):
        print 'in parse_location'       
        item = ComoShamLocation()
        item['category'] = 'location'
        loc = Selector(response).xpath('((//div[@id = "node-2266"]/div/div/div)[1]/div/div/p//text())').extract()
        item['address'] = loc[2]+loc[3]+loc[4]+(loc[5])[1:11]
        item['pin'] = (loc[5])[11:18]
        item['phone'] = (loc[9])[6:20]
        item['fax'] = (loc[10])[6:20]
        item['email'] = loc[12]
        print item['address'],item['pin'],item['phone'],item['fax'],item['email']
        return item
```

Items file:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class ComoShamLocation(Item):
    address = Field()
    pin = Field()
    phone = Field()
    fax = Field()
    email = Field()
    category = Field()
```

Pipeline file:

```
class ComoShamPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.locationdump = csv.writer(open('./scraped data/ComoSham/ComoshamLocation.csv','wb'))
        self.locationdump.writerow(['Address','Pin','Phone','Fax','Email'])


    def process_item(self,item,spider):
        print 'processing item now'
        if item['category'] == 'location':
            print item['address'],item['pin'],item['phone'],item['fax'],item['email']
            self.locationdump.writerow([item['address'],item['pin'],item['phone'],item['fax'],item['email']])
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Is an item generated at the end of your `parse_location` function and has it values?

Comment: Yes, at the end of `parse_location` I am printing it and output is as expected.

Comment: I think you have but I have to ask it: did you configure the ItemPipeline in the `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, its configured in `settings.py`. The pipeline initialisation function gets called. If I put a `print` statement there, it gets printed. Also the csv file is created correctly with the header line. Only `process_item` function is not getting called. Dont know how to debug it.

Comment: Could you show us the `settings.py`?

Comment: It looks like you aren't ever yielding your item.. Try replacing self.parse_location(response) with yield self.parse_location(response)

Comment: @rocktheartsm4l: Adding `yield` to the statement works like a charm. Thanks very much. If you take this out of the comment and post it as answer, I can accept it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is that you are never actually yielding the item. parse_location returns an item to parse, but parse never yields that item.

The solution would be to replace:

```
self.parse_location(response)
```

with

```
yield self.parse_location(response)
```

More specifically, process_item never gets called if no items are yielded.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ITEM_PIPELINES` in settings.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['project_name.pipelines.pipeline_class']
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers above,
1. Remember to add the following line to settings.py!

`ITEM_PIPELINES = {'[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME].pipelines.[YOUR_PIPELINE_CLASS]': 300}`

2. Yield the item when your spider runs! 

`yield my_item`

Comment: correct the ['YOUR_PROJECT_NAME] to '[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME]

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:
I was Dropping all items before my Pipeline get called, so process_item() wasn't getting called but open_spider and close_spider was being called. 
So tmy solution was just change the order to use this Pipeline before the other Pipeline that Drops items.

[Scrapy Pipeline Documentation.](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component)

Just remember that Scrapy calls Pipeline.process_item() only if there is item to process!